# How can I write field value to a json file with boost?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have some json file:

```
{
    ....
    ....
    "frequency_ask": 900
}
```

and need to change field frequency_ask to 1200 for example.

I called my function

```
void setFieldToJson(std::string json, std::string field, int value)
{
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put(field, value);
    std::ostringstream json;

    boost::property_tree::write_json(json, pt);
}
```

with next:

```
setFieldToJson("../config_files/device.json", "frequency_ask", 1200);
```

but doesn't work.

How can I make it correct?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I supposed there is some intent in purposely hiding the `std::string json` parameter with the local `std::ostringstream json` . Not sure what it is, though. What are you *precisely* expecting this code to do ? (and don't say "work"; be precise).

Comment: When I compiled this code, I got an error- not correct format of json. I just want to know how to correct change filed in my json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely that you're using Property Tree, which is *NOT* a JSON library.

Alternatively, it could be that your input is not valid JSON.

Here's my take using Boost JSON:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5900edad09983436)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <fstream>

void setFieldToJson(std::string const& filename, std::string field, int value)
{
    std::string content;
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
        content.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
    }
    boost::json::parse_options opts;
    opts.allow_comments = true;
    opts.allow_invalid_utf8 = false;
    opts.allow_trailing_commas = true;

    auto doc = boost::json::parse(content, {}, opts);
    doc.at(field) = value;

    std::ofstream(filename, std::ios::binary) << doc;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc>1)
    {
        setFieldToJson(
            "device.json", "frequency_ask", std::stoi(argv[1]));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again! But I can't compile it wo errors. First- can just send int value WO stoi function?

Comment: I included #include <boost/json/src.hpp>  to another file whew I read json data. And when I try to include same string to another file, where I want to write some data to json, with your function example, I got a lot of errors, that some data already defined in this file. Very strange behavior

Comment: should I use only one time header <boost/json/src.hpp>? Should I create only 1 file where I will handle read- write operations to json with that library?

Comment: @metcenger That's very normal behaviour; Like I commented in the code `src.hpp` is only for header-only use. See https://github.com/boostorg/json#header-only. Compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98a3f7dfd985f525

Comment: So, either don't go header only, or use it as documented. You can use Boost JSON in as many translation units as you wish. Just don't include `src.hpp` more than once, because that leads to duplicate definitions

Comment: "Can just send in value" - you're not sending anything. You're passing an argument. The argument type is `boost::json::value`. You can pass anything that implicitly converts to `boost::json::value`

Comment: firstly I didn't understand your comment // for header-only what does it mean. Now understand- use only once. One more time- in the one of two files, where I want to use json library I should use #include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only and in the second file where I'll use this library only insert #include <boost/json.hpp>. Correct?

Comment: Yup. <padding/> I think your description could be clearer, but luckily we have the documentation :)